# Basically the opposite MultiSite URL question that most people ask

Tags: multisite, htaccess

Going to install a wordpress multisite in a subdirectory format. So a new site will be `site.com/sitetwo/` or `site.com/sitethree/` but what I need to do for the specific task at hand is change the url to `site.com/string/sitetwo`

I could easily accomplish it with a second install of wordpress in the `/string/` folder but that doesn't sound elegant. I've exhausted all other ideas and would greatly appreciate another perspective.

My wp.org post, with more details:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/multisite-subdirectory-possibly-htaccess-question?replies=1

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this, is to alter the way WordPress maps the request to a blog in your multisite network by using the `sunrise.php` drop-in. Sunrise overwrite the default setup in `wp-includes/ms-settings.php`. There, a bunch of global variables are set up like `$current_blog` or `$current_site`.

To activate this dropin you have to define the constant `SUNRISE` in your wp-config.php:

```
define( 'SUNRISE', TRUE );
```

Now, WordPress looks up for a `sunrise.php` file in your `WP_CONTENT_DIR` directory. (By default it is `/wp-content`).

In this sunrise.php you have to do at least the following things:

- Parse the request to get the domain and the path
- Setup the the global `$current_site` using the function `get_current_site()`
- Looking for your blog in the `wp_blogs` database table using your domain and path.
- With this data, set up the global `$current_blog`

Here's an example of how i played with this. It's not perfect but might get you an idea of how this could look like:

(I use namespaces so be aware of using at least PHP 5.3 or striping the namespace references.)

The shown example does not limit the path segments to two levels like you want but matches the complete path against the database, so that even one or more than two levels are possible as base for a own blog.

```
namespace dna\Blog_Mapping;

sunrise();

/**
 * init the globals $current_blog and $current_site
 *
 * @global $current_blog
 * @global $current_site
 * @global $wpdb
 * @global $path
 * @global $cookie_domain
 * @return void
 */
function sunrise() {

    if ( defined( 'WP_INSTALLING' ) )
        return; # don't touch the installing process

    if ( ! \is_subdomain_install() )
        return;

    /**
     * strip port numbers in the host
     */
    $domain = addslashes( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );
    if ( false !== strpos( $domain, ':' ) ) {
        if ( substr( $domain, -3 ) == ':80' ) {
            $domain = substr( $domain, 0, -3 );
            $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = substr( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0, -3 );
        } elseif ( substr( $domain, -4 ) == ':443' ) {
            $domain = substr( $domain, 0, -4 );
            $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = substr( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0, -4 );
        } else {
            \wp_load_translations_early();
            \wp_die( __( 'Multisite only works without the port number in the URL.' ) );
        }
    }
    $current_site = \get_current_site();

    # setup the sitename to the current_site object
    $current_site = $current_site->site_name;

    # find the blog by domain and path
    $uri  = \parse_url( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ] );
    $path = \preg_replace( '|([a-z0-9-]+.php.*)|', '', $uri[ 'path' ] );
    $path = \str_replace ( '/wp-admin/', '/', $path );

    $current_blog = get_blog_details( $domain, $path );

    # at this point, we are obviously at the root blog
    # using the core function to get blog by root blog id
    if ( ! $current_blog ) {
        $current_blog = \get_blog_details( $current_site->blog_id );
    }

    if ( empty( $current_blog->site_id ) ) {
        $current_blog->site_id = ( isset( $current_site->id ) )
            ? $current_site->id
            : 1;
    }

    $blogname = substr( $domain, 0, strpos( $domain, '.' ) );
    $blogname .= $current_blog->path;

    # set globals like in wp-includes/ms-settings.php
    $GLOBALS[ 'blog_id' ]      = $current_blog->blog_id;
    $GLOBALS[ 'public' ]       = $current_blog->public;
    $GLOBALS[ 'current_site' ] = $current_site;
    $GLOBALS[ 'current_blog' ] = $current_blog;
    $GLOBALS[ 'path' ]         = $current_blog->path;
    $GLOBALS[ 'blogname' ]     = $blogname;
}

/**
 * get the blog details by domain and
 * matching path segments
 *
 * @global $wpdb
 * @param string $domain
 * @param string $path
 * @return \stdClass|FALSE
 */
function get_blog_details( $domain, $path ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $query = $wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT
        *
     FROM
        {$wpdb->blogs}
     WHERE
        domain = %s
     AND
            1 = INSTR( %s, path )
     ORDER BY
        CHAR_LENGTH( path ) DESC
     LIMIT 1",
    $domain,
    $path
);

    $current_blog = $wpdb->get_row( $query );

    if ( empty( $current_blog ) )
        return FALSE;

    return $current_blog;
}
```

Comment: The answer now relies to version 3.9 of WordPress, thanks to @t-f. For Versions prior 3.9 see the original answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/revisions/126176/1

Answer (score 0):

You can install [WP into its own directory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory) and make it a multisite sub-directory.  That way you can have the WP root at site.com/wordpress and subsites like site.com/wordpress/subsite1

You might want to consider if you really need a subsite when a page or post may be adequate, especially something for profiles, site.com/staff/profile1

Comment: Thanks, but already eliminated that as a possibility. The sub site will have unique menus, galleries and multiple pages.. also a unique template. A separate site seems most logical at the moment. (if it were a single page i'd do just that)